# How to generate a sequence considering deleted entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sequence

Assuming I have a simple hibernate entity like so

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
    @Id
    private long id;

    // Other fields...
}
```

I want to generate sequence for the id column with consideration of any deleted entities. Meaning I don't want the sequence to be incremented for every new entity saved to the database, but to reuse values assigned to entities that were deleted.
For example in the db I have these entities saved

```
|---------------------|
|          ID         |
|---------------------|
|          1          |
|---------------------|
|          2          |
|---------------------|
```

So the next entity id should get the value 3. But in case the entity with id '*1*' was deleted, the next time I save an entity to the database I want its id to be '*1*'

How can this behaviour can be implemented using Hibernate?

Comment: Could you explain why do you need it?

Comment: I guess that this question should be rather addressed to the underlying database. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984196/postgresql-gapless-sequences) question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA, Reuse of deleted ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031469/jpa-reuse-of-deleted-id)  Or this? [hibernate @GeneratedValue , how to deal with deleted rows. in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651754/hibernate-generatedvalue-how-to-deal-with-deleted-rows-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, a DB sequence doesn't work that way. You will have to implement a DB query to get the minimum available ID and set the entity ID manually.

Comment: And doing that can lead to all kinds of nasty concurrency issues, which is exactly why sequences don't do this.

Comment: Thank you. I also read the answers Alex Rudenko suggested that basically said it may cause performance issues as well